# How to make two mouseMoveEvents work together

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QGraphicsEllipseItem and a QGraphicsScene, both of which have custom mouseMoveEvent and mousePressEvent functions. However, for some reason, the mouseMoveEvent only seems to work for the QGraphicsScene. My guess is that the QGraphicsScene event is overriding the QGraphicsEllipseItem event. But, the mousePressEvent works for both for some reason. Is there any way to make the mouseMoveEvent work for both of them as well?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class CustomEllipseItem(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomEllipseItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("EllipseItem mousePressEvent")
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print("EllipseItem mouseMoveEvent")
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)


class CustomScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("Scene mousePressEvent")
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print("Scene mouseMoveEvent")
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    scene = CustomScene()
    view = QGraphicsView(scene)

    ellipse_item = CustomEllipseItem(0, 0, 100, 100)
    scene.addItem(ellipse_item)

    view.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Note that the default implementation of QGraphicsItem (what happens with `super().mousePressEvent(event)`) prevents the item to receive any further move/release event. The behavior is exactly the same as it is for standard QWidgets: `mousePressEvent()` doesn't accept the event, and the widget (item) doesn't get any further mouse event. Test it by yourself: either remove the `super()` line from `mousePressEvent()` or add `event.accept()` **after** it. Then carefully read the documentation about such event handlers for both QWidget *and* QGraphicsItem.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to simply have both events fire when moving mouse from inside of the ellipse item's radius then you can achieve this by adding the `ItemIsSelectable` flag to your `CustomEllipseItem`.

For example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class CustomEllipseItem(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomEllipseItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFlag(self.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable)  # <--- here

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("EllipseItem mousePressEvent")
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print("EllipseItem mouseMoveEvent")
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)


class CustomScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("Scene mousePressEvent")
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print("Scene mouseMoveEvent")
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    scene = CustomScene()
    view = QGraphicsView(scene)

    ellipse_item = CustomEllipseItem(0, 0, 100, 100)
    scene.addItem(ellipse_item)

    view.show()

    app.exec_()
```